# Interpretation of a decision tree when the response and predictors are continuous variables

Tags: r, plot, classification, prediction, decision-tree

[image]

The response variable is MDD while independent variables are gravel, NMC, fines, GS, PL, LL, and sand.
Anyone should kindly assist in interpreting the output. I need it in my research. The output is from M5 model using R version 4.0.5

Comment: Your tree does not look like an M5 Tree.  All of the nodes are constants.  M5 should have linear functions at the nodes.

Comment: This set of code gave me the tree plot:                                                                                 
 ```m5_model <- rpart(MDD ~ ., data = mydata)``` 
  ```rpart.plot(m5_model, digits=3)```

Comment: Is anything wrong with the code? I used **R version 4.0.5** and **R studio version 1.2.5033**

Comment: `rpart` implements CART  not M5.  There is nothing wrong with using rpart/CART  but it is not M5. If you want an implementation of M5,  take a look at the Cubist package.